# Python + PIL screenshot comparing

Tags: python, compare, screenshot, python-imaging-library

I've made a program that compares screenshots grabbed by PIL, stored in a table and I use `ImageChops.difference` to compare them.

The program works pretty good but there is one problem. The exactly same screenshots (e.g if you take two screenshots of your desktop with 1 second interval) don't have the exactly same pixels. I found this by using Photoshop with a lot of zoom. So in some cases the program returns some wrong values.

Is there any way to get exactly same pixels from similar screenshots so I don't have to use thresholds? Or any other way to succeed high comparing accuracy for my database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of your pixels are different, nor what differences you're looking for exactly, so it's a bit hard to give help.

Turning off all animations and desktop effects should help with getting consistent screenshots, of course. I'm sure one can write a tool that does this.

Also, saving the screenshots as JPEG (or any lossy format) is also right out, as I'm sure you know.

There's also a utility called [pdiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/) which compares images based on perceptual differences, rather than straight value based differences. It might help you, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.The program takes some screenshots of images with text within,from the web and saves them,using PIL, in a grayscale bmp(not lossy) format. When I take the same screenshot of the same image, with the same method, it looks the same, but the pixels are different when I zoom in a lot.

Comment: Are you using ClearType (Windows) or somesuch font-readabilty-improvement method on your system?

Comment: Yeap, I'm using ClearType. I believe this happens because of PIL, the screenshot is handled differently somewhere in ImageGrab or ImageCrop...I can't said for sure.

Comment: ClearType does mess with the pixels a bit, but it should be safe if your screen is static. If you distrust your screen grabber, use PrtSc to grab some images and compare them, to see what the problem is. Then take it up with the PIL mailing list if there's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Capis,

As far as I know Open CV is the best library for Image processing. I coded in C though. However it has a pythonic wrapper too. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html Give it a shot.